# Split zero in String

Tags: java, webdriver

Guys I have `int` value parse to `string []`, I should write:

---

```
if (first element == 0)
 split it
return value without 0 at start.
```

> For example I have 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10,... 20...
>   30..

---

So in return in will split `0` for value where `0` is the first element, and return to me next:

---

> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,... 20... 30..

---

Actually I need it for my calendar, I've take date from it but it return to me days like `01, 02, 03` and so on. Here my method code:

---

```
public String setCurrentCalendarDay() throws TestException, ParseException{
        if (!getPage().getSession().CanRun())
            throw new TestException(Page.InvalidStateMessage);
        String currentDate = "";
        Date date = new Date();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
        currentDate = formatter.format(date);
        return currentDate;
    }
```

Comment: So, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first option is to use `new SimpleDateFormat("d")` and not `("dd")` so you just have one digit minimum and not two.

The second option is to use a regex like this one `return currentDate.replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "")` so it will replace all first `0` by nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to achieve. But maybe you are looking for a way to remove leading `0` characters from a String

```
String currentDate = "01";
System.out.println("currentDate = " + currentDate);
System.out.println("currentDate = " + currentDate.replaceFirst("^0*", ""));
```

**output**

```
currentDate = 01
currentDate = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [String.startsWith(String prefix)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29)

From the JavaDocs:

> Returns: true if the character sequence represented by the argument is a prefix of the character sequence represented by this string; false otherwise. Note also that true will be returned if the argument is an empty string or is equal to this String object as determined by the equals(Object) method.

And then using [String.substring(int beginIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29)

Don't forget to also check if the number actually equals 0.